# Cosmic Calendar

Tags: homework-and-exercises

So for an assignment I was given a event/ occurrence and was asked to find its cosmic date/ time. Here are a few examples of ones it asked for, I was wondering if there was a formula to find the date and time with the given information.

Big Bang 13.7 billion years ago

Radiation Dominant Era Begins 10,000 years after big bang

Matter Dominant Era Begins 70,000 years after big bang

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this is one of those "If the history of the universe were compressed to a year" assignments or something. *If* that's true, then I fear you've missed the point of the assignment. In any event, there is not enough information to answer, since "cosmic time" is not a term outside this assignment. Moreover, this probably runs afoul of our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, you would begin at 12:00 a.m. on January 1. Taking the big bang to be the first event (13.7 billion years ago) and dividing this time into 365 days, you find that roughly 1 calendar day equals 37.5 million years. You can then divide this by 24 to find that one calendar hour corresponds to roughly 1.56 million years. Using this type of approach you could determine where dates would lie within one cosmic year.

Edit: I am operating under the assumption that you are using a notion of "cosmic calendar" akin to Sagan's *Cosmos*. I haven't heard this term outside that context, as one of the comments suggested.